# How can I arrange my figures like a self-defined matrix using LaTex?

Tags: floats, plot, width, height

I have three plots: a.eps, b.eps, and c.eps

How can I arrange my figures like the following, so I will later refer to them as Fig.1 (a) and so on? Can I tweak the height and width of a, b, and c?

[image: figure matrix]

Comment: Check out the subfigure package https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure?lang=en

Comment: @jak123 Thanks! Doesn't seem to work on Overleaf, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:dragratio} 
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:dragratio2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\[\baselineskip]
        \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.9\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:dragratio3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \centering
        \caption{(a) Numerical solutions for the constant-curvature body, $F(x)=x(1-x), x \in (0,1)$, at small times. This figure shows the drag force $D$ versus the scaled mass $M$ for various values of the ratio between the inertia $I$ and the mass $M$, i.e. for various values of $R=\frac{I}{M}$. Here $g=10$ and $A=0.7$. (b) As for (a) but with $A=0.5$. (c) As for (a) and (b) but with $A=0.25$.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! This is neat. Thank you!